# Find the inverse of the function $y=log_a(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})$,$(a>0,a\neq 1)$.

Tags: functions, proof-explanation

Find the inverse of the function $y=log_a(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})$,$(a>0,a\neq 1)$.

I got this problem from a book called Problems in Calculus of One Variable by I.A Maron, where it was given as an example .

The solution given in the book is as follows:

> The function $y=log_a(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})$,$(a>0,a\neq 1)$ is defined for all $x$ , since $\sqrt{x^2+1}>|x|$ , and is odd . It increases for positive values of $x$ , hence it increases everywhere and has an inverse function . Solving the equation $y=log_a(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})$ with respect to $x$ we find that $a^y=x+\sqrt{x^2+1}$;$a^{-y}=-x+\sqrt{x^2+1}$, whence $x=\frac{1}{2}(a^y+a^{-y})=\sin(h\ln a)$.

However, I am not getting how are they saying "hence, it increases everywhere "? I mean how do they conclude it for the negative values of $x$ ? Now, we can easily calculate the inverse by the method depicted above but they are essentially trying to prove that the inverse function exist as well . So, the only way to show it is that  is , it is a  bijective function . Now, it is onto from definition.  But we must prove its injective ...I am not getting how to prove it. The other method to prove its bijectivity is showing the function is monotonic . This is the way how it's done in the book, but I dont get how are they proving it...What happens when $x<0$ ? I am not quite getting it...

Comment: it is hyperbolic trig in disguise, set  $x=\sinh(u)$ to see the simplification.

Comment: @zwim Thank you! Actually I haven't studied hyperbolic geometry...I only know about the basic formulas of $\sinh(x),\cosh(x),...$  but how is the function bijective isn't very much clear to me...

Comment: A better argument notes$$\frac{d}{dx}(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})=1+\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\ge1-\frac{|x|}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}>0.$$

Comment: it is easy to get: $x=\dfrac{a^{2y}-1}{2a^y}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- method 1: using hyperbolic trigonometric functions.

We have $\cosh(u)=\dfrac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}$ and $\sinh(u)=\dfrac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$

They are both $C^\infty$ smooth and each other derivative (easy to prove) and since the exponential is positive, we get that $\sinh$ is strictly monotonic (and continuous) hence bijective.

Since it is bijective let set $x=\sinh(u)$

$\begin{align}\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})
&=\ln\Big(\sinh(u)+\underbrace{\sqrt{\sinh(u)^2+1}}_{\cosh^2-\sinh^2=1}\ \Big)
=\ln\Big(\sinh(u)+\underbrace{\sqrt{\cosh(u)^2}}_{\cosh>0}\ \Big)\\\\
&=\ln\Big(\sinh(u)+\cosh(u)\Big)=\ln(e^u)=u\end{align}$

Therefore that log function is simply the reciprocal function $\sinh^{-1}$ also noted $\operatorname{arcsinh}$

If you deal with $\log_a$ instead, there is just an additional $\ln(a)$ to consider (i.e. $y=\frac 1{\ln(a)}u)$

- method 2 : direct calculation

$\sqrt{x^2+1}>\sqrt{x^2}=|x|\implies x+\sqrt{x^2+1}>0$ and the function is defined everywhere.

The log expression is composed of derivable functions and we are well inside the definition domain so it is derivable itself.

$\ln(a)y'(x)=\dfrac{1+\frac x{\sqrt{x^2+1}}}{x+\sqrt{x^2+1}}=\dfrac 1{\sqrt{x^2+1}}>0$

So $y(x)$ is strictly monotonous (and since also derivable hence continuous) it is a bijection.

You can then proceed for the inversion as proposed in the book.