# Why does $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\cosh^{-1}n}{H_n}=1$?

Tags: limits, hyperbolic-functions, harmonic-numbers

$H_n$ represents the $n\text{th}$ harmonic number. I was messing around with Desmos when I happened to come across this. I typed it into WolframAlpha which confirmed that the limit is equal to $1$ but did not have a step-by-step solution available. I have not formally learned about hyperbolic functions or harmonic numbers. My only idea is to use l'Hopital's rule (I got the derivatives of each function from WolframAlpha):

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\cosh^{-1}n}{H_n}=1$$

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2-1}}}{\frac{\pi^2}{6}-H^{(2)}_n}=1$$

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{6}{(\pi^2-6H^{(2)}_n)\sqrt{n^2-1}}=1$$

L'hopital's rule would once again apply but I feel like it would not help.

Comment: Hint: large $n$ satisfy$$\operatorname{arcosh}n-\ln n\approx\ln2,\,H_n-\ln n\approx\gamma.$$

Comment: remember that hyperbolic inverse functions are representable with logarithm i.e. $\cosh^{-1}(n)=\ln(n+\sqrt{n^2-1})\sim \ln(2n)$ when $n\gg 1$ (e.g. see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4588346/399263))

Comment: Use the fact that $H_n/\log n\to 1$ and hence the desired limit is equal to the limit of $\cosh^{-1}n/\log n$ which is same as limit of $m/\log\cosh m$ as $m\to\infty$.